# How can I have all existing users sign out from Google when updating the app?

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-play-games

I am trying to integrate Google Play Game Services into my app. (I am really having trouble with it so please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324399/cannot-sign-in-google-play-game-services) as well..) And I actually have been using Google Sign In which uses Web Client ID and trying to switch it to Google Play Games which uses Android Client ID.

What I want to know is having every users sign out when the user updates the app. Otherwise if the user already signed in using web client id and try to use Google Play Games functionality, app crashes.

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
: You need to a create Splash Activity which will initially check for the Build Version

> Create a Splash Activity and add this method to it.

```
        public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      forcedLogout();
                    }
                },5*1000);
            }
        }

            private void forcedLogout(){

                if (myPrefs.getLong(PREF_APP_CURRENT_VERSION,0) != BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE){
                    //call logout method
                 }else{
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));

                        finish();
    }
}
```

> then add shared preferences in your login activity.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefEditor.putLong(PREF_APP_CURRENT_VERSION,BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
prefEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Wait actually I am a bit confused.  Can you explain your approach? Because when the user updates the app, it should already update to a new version so I think user doesn't log out.

Comment: I mean after saving the current version in SharedPreferences, it always equals and cannot call logout method.

Comment: I made one mistake, add this forced logout method  in a Splash Activity which will initially check the requirements and then add Shared Preferences to your login activity.